# How can a NoSQL database handle object-oriented data?

Tags: mongodb, cassandra, nosql

If I wanted to use a NoSQL datastore, such as Apache Cassandra or MongoDB, to store data that is well described as object oriented?

The issue I have is that while OOP principles work because I have objects that can be nicely organized with an object tree using inheritance (*i.e.*  and  are a subtypes of ), I cannot define ALL of the potential attributes on each object type at compile time.  I need to have the flexibility for the users to define new attributes and assign data to them.

I'm liking the idea of a document DB that is flexible for new key-value pairs in the document (object) and full-text search / MapReduce to find data.

Is this easy to do with these platforms?

Comment: If you want to get a feel for MongoDB, you can play around on a scratchpad I built for it: https://saturnapi.com/

Answer (score 0):

In general, yes, if you wish to have the software more in control of the data vs. the database, then the NoSQL offerings are typically more "impedance matched" for this use case.

(Sales warning)  MongoDB, with the document model and introspective-data-as-schema paradigm, is particularly well-suited for the use case you describe.

Answer (score 0):

You can you any document based NoSQL solution for that. Which one is better is based on your requirements. If speed is a concern for you then use Tarantool, if not then Cassandra or Monga suit well.